# Problem including gems in Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, tmail

My Rails app uses the TMail plugin, but it requires a modification to Attachment.rb.

The modification is recognized and loaded by Rails on my development machine, but in the production environment on my hosting provider (Rails Playground), the system version of TMail is loaded and not our custom version.

Online document about the best way to include or freeze gems is confusing on many sites.

Anyone have a definitive answer about the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rake gems:unpack:dependencies
```

This will copy all gems you specified in environment.rb into vendor/gems
These will be used on the remote machine. If you modify them in the vendor directory I see no reason this should not be used as well.